# can we insert or update data in table from RLS policy in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security

I've created table `"clientID_dbUser_mapping"` which contains `client id (e.g 1,2,3)` and `DB User name (u1,u2,u3)`

Now created another table `"test_data"` which contains `id(PK), data(text), client_id(FK)`

created RLS policy for `"test_data"` to access the appropriate logged in db_user data

here is policy :

```
CREATE POLICY client_id_testdata_policy ON test_data
FOR ALL
USING (client_id =
              (SELECT client_id
               FROM client_dbuser_mapping
               WHERE db_user_name = current_user)
      )
WITH CHECK (client_id =
              (SELECT client_id
               FROM client_dbuser_mapping
               WHERE db_user_name = current_user)
           );
```

This is working fine for `SELECT/UPDATE/DELETE`

for `INSERT` I want to add default data of `client_id` in `"test_data"` from `"clientID_dbUser_mapping"` table coz it contains client id as per db_user_name

so how can I achieve this through RLS policy (do i need to change something in my existing policy) or need to create new policy ?

is it possible or not?

Comment: Probably a `BEFORE` trigger.

Comment: Except any trigger.. is it possible to achieve?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe should I try Trigger or Rules?

Comment: Triggers, by all means. Avoid rules.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe need little more help. [can you check code](https://codeshare.io/r9QVLE) I have called function `clientid_by_dbuser()` as DEFAULT value in my `client_id` column of `test_data` table. need confirmation that can I use (is this correct way?) DEFAULT value from function as given in link or Trigger is only option.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if I understood the requirement correctly, but if you want to force the `client_id` to a certain value upon `INSERT`, use a trigger:

```
CREATE FUNCTION set_client_id() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   SELECT cdm.client_id INTO NEW.client_id
   FROM client_dbuser_mapping AS cdm
   WHERE cdm.db_user_name = current_user;

   RETURN NEW;
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER set_client_id BEFORE INSERT ON test_data
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_client_id();
```